# Should I delete the "Recovered Items" folder?

Tags: macos, trash, alias

When I upgraded to Yosemite in October, it had some problems during the process, but after it finally installed, everything worked great.  It still does, but I just need some more space for Guild Wars 2 (which is around 17 GB since the last time I checked).

Today, I checked my storage status, and it was around 412 GB.  I looked around for some heavy-weight stuff, and I found `Recovered Items` (probably from that problem during the installation process) which is 26.31 GB.  Huge, yes?  Very...

Anyway, in that folder are 3 more (1 is an alias for `/Users`), and the other 2 are `Library` and `System`.  I suspect these 2 folders must be from Mavericks.  So, I'm wondering, **is it 100% safe to delete this monster?**

P.S: When I moved the Users alias to the trash, I checked its info again, it said the original is located in `/Users/(username)/.Trash/Users`.  I haven't deleted it yet, but I don't think it'll affect the parent.

Comment: If you move them to trash but do not empty it, then see if everything is working as it should you are fine, since you can recover from trash in case you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might find a "Recovered Items" folder in the Trash. Don't worry, you can safely delete this folder.

Comment: It only appeared in Macintosh HD (`/`).  Is it still safe to delete?

Comment: Are any of these 'Recovered' applications in your Home/Applications directory? If so, and they all still work, then you should be able to delete the Recovered Items folder, since it's more than likely what OS X renames your Previous System when it updates the OS.